# How do "case tables" work in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

As part of our assignment we are supposed to do various functions with matrices. For the menu, we are assigned to use a "case table" (which is implemented as a 2-D array with each row containing only a letter constant and its corresponding function)

I really cannot make sense of the notes, and the book is zero help (it doesn't mention them at all)

```
    .data
CaseTable BYTE 'A'  ; lookup value
    DWORD Process_A ; address of procedure
    EntrySize = ($ - CaseTable)
    BYTE 'B'
    DWORD Process_B
    BYTE 'C'
    DWORD Process_C
    BYTE 'D'
    DWORD Process_D

NumberOfEntries = ($ - CaseTable) / EntrySize
….
segment .text
...
    mov ebx, CaseTable  ; point EBX to the table
    mov ecx,NumberOfEntries ; loop counter

L1: cmp al,[ebx]    ; match found?
    jne L2  ; no: continue
    call PTR [ebx + 1]  ; yes: call the procedure
    jmp L3  ; and exit the loop
L2: add ebx,EntrySize   ; point to next entry
    loop L1 ; repeat until ECX = 0

L3:
```

Can someone help me make sense of this?

Comment: If you're familiar with C it might be more helpful to think of it is a `struct` rather than a 2D array. `struct { char lookup; function_ptr_t process; } CaseTable[] = { { 'A', Process_A }, /* ... */ };` `#define NumberOfEntries (sizeof(CaseTable)/sizeof(CaseTable[0]))`

Comment: Btw, it's not really a two-dimensional array. It's an array of elements, each of which has 2 elements of its own. Arrays typically have elements of the same size. "BYTE 'A'" and "DWORD Process_A" don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is trivial. If you don't know enough assembly language, try understanding the following equivalent C code (I took the liberty of defining Process_*() as printing distinct letters and throwing in main()):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Process_A(void)
{
  printf("A\n");
}

void Process_B(void)
{
  printf("B\n");
}

void Process_C(void)
{
  printf("C\n");
}

void Process_D(void)
{
  printf("D\n");
}

typedef struct
{
  char Char;
  void (*Subroutine)(void);
} CaseTableEntry;

CaseTableEntry CaseTable[] =
{
  { 'A', &Process_A }, // equivalent to "BYTE 'A'" + "DWORD Process_A"
  { 'B', &Process_B },
  { 'C', &Process_C },
  { 'D', &Process_D }
};

void Process(char Char)
{
  const size_t NumberOfEntries = sizeof(CaseTable) / sizeof(CaseTableEntry);
  CaseTableEntry* entry = &CaseTable[0]; // equiv to "mov ebx, CaseTable"
  size_t count = NumberOfEntries; // equiv to "mov ecx, NumberOfEntries"

  do
  {
    // "L1:" would be here
    if (entry->Char == Char) // equiv to "cmp al,[ebx]" + "jne L2"
    {
      entry->Subroutine(); // equiv to "call PTR [ebx + 1]"
      break; // equiv to "jmp L3"
    }
    // "L2:" would be here
    entry++; // equiv to "add ebx, EntrySize"
  } while (--count > 0); // equiv to "loop L1"
  // "L3:" would be here
}

int main(void)
{
  Process('A');
  Process('B');
  Process('X');
  Process('C');
  Process('D');
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

The only problems here can be things like `$` and `mov ebx, CaseTable`.

[$ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $.](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5)

Hence `EntrySize = ($ - CaseTable)` calculates the size of the first entry of the table and likewise `NumberOfEntries = ($ - CaseTable) / EntrySize` first calculates the entire table size and then divides it by the size of one entry giving you the number of the table entries.

Unlike in other assemblers (e.g. MASM and TASM), in NASM `mov ebx, CaseTable` means loading into ebx the address of the object named `CaseTable`. In other assemblers this can mean reading into ebx the first 4 bytes from the object named `CaseTable`.
Similarly, `DWORD Process_A` defines a DWORD containing the address of the object named `Process_A`.
In other assemblers the equivalents may need to be written as `mov ebx, OFFSET CaseTable` and `DWORD OFFSET Process_A`.

For the rest, please consult your book, [the official NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html) and [Intel's](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) / [AMD's](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx#manuals) x86 CPU manuals. Do your homework, basically. If anything isn't clear, come and ask *specific* questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seeing it in C really made sense of it all.
I apologize for not being specific; I was referring to the allocation of the caseTable, but it is all clear now.

Comment: No prob. Please mark the answers that have answered your questions as `the` answers. For that there's a check mark to the left of every answer.